# Why do I have to give an index to element and .files method in jQuery to access value?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I want to get the value of an  input tag (type file).

If I remove any of the indexes, then there is no value to send or use for ajax

```
        doc=$(document).find('#csv_file')[0].files[0];
```

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="csv_file">Upload Csv</label>
            <input type="file" name="csv_file" id="csv_file" class="form-control" >
        </div>
```

Comment: If you have an array `var arr = [1,2,3];` would you expect to be able to use it without indices?  `arr[0]`?  Why do you have to use them, because that's how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation :

Jquery:
$(document).find('#csv_file') will return a jQuery **collection** not a single object. That is why you have to use [0].

MDN:
.files always returns a FileList object that lists *every selected file*. This is useful when you have the multiple attribute, otherwise you have to use [0] to access the single file selected.

Comment: so, if there was document.getElementById("csv_file") so i don't have to add any index

Comment: Correct, not while accessing the element. But when you are accessing the file will still have to use a [0].